# Apple.com home page slider navigation

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I like navigation of slider/carousel Apple's home page website, do you know about some free template similar to this? I am not expert in js/jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lot of free js carousel:
https://dcrazed.com/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/